# CDK Jest not able to instantiate class

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, ts-jest

I have a class like below:

```
export class AbstractClass extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: SomeProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Another class which is extending the above one:

```
export class MyLambdaStack extends AbstractClass {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: SomeProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

I am trying to write the unit tests for `MyLambdaStack` class.

This is the unit test (`MyLambdaStack.test.ts`):

```
describe("AskEC2 Health Monitor Lambda Stack", () => {
    const app = new App();
    const props: SomeProps = {...};
    const myLambdaStack = new MyLambdaStack(app, `test-id`, props);

    test("Placeholder test", () => {});
}
```

I keep getting error:

```
TypeError: MyLambdaStack_1.MyLambdaStack is not a constructor
```

I believe this error is coming due to the class being extended upon. If I create an instance of `AbstractClass` which is extending cdk.Stack, everything works fine.

Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I could not replicate your error.  There's nothing theoretically unworkable with the Stack inheritance pattern, nor anything obviously wrong with your code.

Working example:

```js
import { Construct } from "constructs";
import { App, Stack, StackProps, aws_lambda as lambda } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { Template } from "aws-cdk-lib/assertions";

export class AbstractClass extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
  }
}

export class MyLambdaStack extends AbstractClass {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    new lambda.Function(this, "Lambda", {
      code: new lambda.InlineCode(
        "exports.handler = async (event) => console.log(event)"
      ),
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
      handler: "index.handler",
    });
  }
}

// ✅ passes
test("MyLambdaStack", () => {
  const app = new App();

  const stack = new MyLambdaStack(app, "MyTestStack", {
    env: { region: "us-east-1", account: "123456789012" },
  });

  const template = Template.fromStack(stack);

  template.resourcePropertiesCountIs("AWS::Lambda::Function", {}, 1);
});
```

Note that if the goal is resource code reuse, the CDK recommends [composing Construct subclasses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-constructs-model) instead of Stack inheritance:

> [W}hen building your application's higher-level logical units from multiple AWS resources, represent each logical unit as a Construct, not as a Stack... By using constructs for building and stacks for deploying, you improve reuse potential of your infrastructure and give yourself more flexibility in how it's deployed.

Comment: Do you think cdk version or jest version might affect it?

Comment: Not likely given you say the "abstract" class works as expected.  Does my code run in your environment?